# Meteor JS: call event.preventDefault() if error happened in Meteor method

Tags: javascript, meteor, event-handling

I'm trying to stop the default behavior of the click event handler if error happened during the execution of some Meteor method which i'm calling using `Meteor.call()`, the method throws an Exception if error happened, but i can't find the right way!
I tried to put Meteor.call() in a try/catch block but nothing got caught:

```
'click .toggle-checked' (event) {
        try {
            Meteor.call('tasks.setChecked', 1, !this.checked);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("Error caught!");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
},
```

Also I tried to pass a callback to Meteor.call() that stops the event default behavior but it didn't work either, it seems that the event handler finishes its work before the callback get called:

```
'click .toggle-checked' (event) {
        Meteor.call('tasks.setChecked', 1, !this.checked, function (error, result) {
            if(error) {
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log("error happened!", error, event);
            }

        });
        console.log("getting out!");
},
```

Comment: The event finishes before the callback is called. Can you explain a little bit what are you working on and why do you need something like this?

Comment: I'm following meteor todolist tutorial. when the user check any checkbox i call this method to update the database, when the method fails to update the database it throws an exception, but the event handler continue working and check the box in the client page.
i want the event handler to prevent the default behavior (checking the checkbox) if this methods fails to update the database.

Comment: In the catch event, you should add some action if the call fails, but you can't rely on the default event.